# How to run a file on server on html-button click

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, apache

how do I manage to execute a Python-file or a bash-script on a server via a press of a html-button without using a framework?

I have tried several versions of Ajax-Calls suggested in answers to similar questions, but none of them seem to work for me.

Note: Im using an Apache-Server on a RaspberryPi

Comment: The HTML button should trigger an Ajax call (in JS) that reaches a route on your server, and the server can then execute the script.

Comment: How to I make the server execute the script? I tried making an Ajax call to my script on the server but it did not run it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html), you should configure apache to run CGI script, define an url prefix that maps a directory that contains your script and finally your script must return output in a particular way, or Apache will return an error message.

So, for example, if you define an url prefix like:

```
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/path/to/your/script/cgi-bin/"
```

you can create a simple anchor to execute your script, you don't need to use ajax for this.

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/myscript.sh">click me</a>
```

To successful run your script you should follow apache directive in "[Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)"